# Does YUM package is available in python 3 Redhat 8

Tags: python-3.x, yum

I am using YUM package in python 2.7 and things are working fine, but now we are switching to new Redhat 8 which is having python 3 as default, so we are looking to upgrade to python 3 but we are getting this issue

for line -

```
  import yum
```

we get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yum'
```

months before i read somewhere that yum is not ported for python 3

so do we have yum package for python 3 now or we should go with some other similar package ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can still install Python2 if you really need this module

Comment: yeah i can, but we dont to use python 2 on new machine